# Is my platy pregnant? I'm not sure

Tags: fish

I got this platy the other day, I think she pregnant, but I'm not sure as it's my first time keeping platy fish.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Pets, yes the platy definitely looks pregnant and the pregnancy looks quite advanced because of the prominent gravid spot (dark spot on the abdomen).

Comment: Thank you so much for replying & I thought so just wanted to make sure so I can prepare for when r when she releases the fry as I don't want the otjer9or her eating them all as I plan to keep a few ❤️

Comment: If she was in a tank with males , she is gravid.

Comment: There is males in the tank too